# Getting error when patching pan ugen to output: "Pan MUST be ticked with stereo output!"

Tags: java, processing, minim

I'm rigging up a minim test to take two audio files, pan them hard left/right, and play them from an output. When I remove references to the pan patch, everything plays just fine, but when I add it back in I get the java.lang.IllegalArgumentException from the title above.

I tried setting the 'tick' but it seems to expect a float array, and I don't understand what that's supposed to correspond to. What should I be supplying to the tick function to make the error go away? It says it should be a 'channel', but how do I derive that from the AudioRecordingStream that I have to load into the FilePlayer object to use ugens? The documentation is a bit sparse here: http://code.compartmental.net/minim/pan_method_tick.html

At first I thought it was expecting the pan patch to come *after* the AudioOutput out, but that didn't help.

Here's the relevant bits of the code (this is happening in the setup function, and all objects are declared at the global level above it):

```
pan = new Pan(0);
//pan.tick( not sure what goes here ); 

out = minim.getLineOut(Minim.STEREO);

AudioRecordingStream file = minim.loadFileStream("file.mp3", 1024, false);
player = new FilePlayer(file);

pan.setPan(-1);
player.patch(pan).patch(out);
```

Any ideas what I might be missing here? I feel like I'm pretty close.